# how to returning response to AJAX from jsp

Tags: jquery, jsp-tags

I have a problem in returning response to AJAX from JSP page.

i have tried this code:

```
response.getWriter().print(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

What is the type of result you are trying to return? If it is plain text or html, then set content type before writing it out.

```
response.setContentType("text/html");  
response.getWriter().write(result);
```

If you are trying to return other java objects like list or map, you should convert it to json object and set content type accordingly,

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().write(json);
```

Comment: what is result?

Answer (score 2):

What i uses for returning XML content from JSP to Ajax:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/xml;charset=UTF-8"%>
<%
[....i did my stuff here ....]
  response.getWriter().write(res.toString());  
%>
```

Works like a charm!

I have not used other response than XML, but i suppose, if you set the `contentType` properly, it will be similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to return HTML response to your AJAX query then you need to write "regular" JSP that will generate the HTM page when you call it.

If you are trying to return non-HTML response then I think it will be better to use Servlet.